# Constrain Typescript generics to object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi guys,

I'm not that familiar with [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), but here is the following I want to achieve, and I'm currently struggling with:

Create an object with the function `createObject` as defined below. As argument you can pass in **only** a parameter of type Object.

It returns the passed in argument, but modified by an type and detail property).

This is, what I have done so far.

```
function createObject<T extends object>(options: T): T {
  if (!options.type) {
    if (options.showDetail) {
      options.type = 'text';
      options.detail = 'Some detail';
    } else {
      options.type = 'simple';
      options.detail = '';
    }
  }
  return options
}
```

When I execute my function:

```
const objectConfig = {
  name: 'Steven',
  age: 28,
}

const newObj = createObject(objectConfig);
```

Inside the function `createObject`, `options.type, options.showDetail, options.detail` are highlighted red. Typescript complains about:

> [Line 4] Property 'type' does not exist on type 'T'.
>
> [Line 3] Property 'showDetail' does not exist on type 'T'.
>
> [Line 5, 8] Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'T'.

Furthermore, returning the Generic, won't return the modified argument, instead just the input argument. I.e. I won't get Typescript hints about the detail/type property of `newObj`.

My IDE just gives me type hints for the age and name property. As expected since I return erroneously just the input argument.

How can I get a proper typescript solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Your the generic object is being used as a type, so you must extend a type that has those property names: create that interface and extend that. Secondly, your `objectConfig` construct does not match the types for the properties you've extended. `Some detail` being a string will cause issues with you passing `age` as a number type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... The problem is you are writing TypeScript as if it is just like JavaScript. That's not how it works. Here's a solution that *just works* but you need to start writing TypeScript like you write any other OOP language<sup>1</sup>.

```
interface OptionExtensions {
    type?: string,
    showDetail?: boolean,
    detail?: string
}

function createObject<T extends object>(options: T): T & OptionExtensions {
    let optionsExtended: T & OptionExtensions = options;
    if (!optionsExtended.type) {
        if (optionsExtended.showDetail) {
            optionsExtended.type = 'text';
            optionsExtended.detail = 'Some detail';
        } else {
            optionsExtended.type = 'simple';
            optionsExtended.detail = '';
        }
    }
    return optionsExtended;
}

let foo = createObject({
    name: "Steven",
    age: 28
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20OptionExtensions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3F%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20showDetail%3F%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20detail%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createObject%3CT%20extends%20object%3E(options%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%26%20OptionExtensions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20optionsExtended%3A%20T%20%26%20OptionExtensions%20%3D%20options%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!optionsExtended.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(optionsExtended.showDetail)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionsExtended.type%20%3D%20'text'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionsExtended.detail%20%3D%20'Some%20detail'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionsExtended.type%20%3D%20'simple'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optionsExtended.detail%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20optionsExtended%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20createObject(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Steven%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%2028%0D%0A%7D)%3B). You can check `foo` has all properties that you would expect (by writing "foo." and seeing the suggestions).

Footnote 1:
By this I mean because TypeScript has nice [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) and [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) it will allow you to make things work without explicitly writing types and making interfaces but not for too long. Think how would you write things in a OOP language and then make appropriate abstractions and models.

Comment: You might want to keep the `<T extends object>` though, otherwise you won't get noticed if you plug in e.g. a number or a string.